# É possível usar apenas o get sem o set no Object.defineProperty?

Tags: javascript

Necessito de obter mais informações sobre os atributos `get` e `set` do método `Object.defineProperty()`.

Eu entendi que `get` chama uma função quando uma propriedade é lida e que `set` chama uma função quando um valor é gravado em uma propriedade.

Posso usar um sem o outro? Por exemplo, definir o `get` sem definir o `set`?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como proceder. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, pode definir apenas um deles conforme a sua necessidade. É comum definir ambas ou definir só o `get`, mas nada impede de fazer o contrário.

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop', {
  get: function() { return propValue; },
});
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/Getter.js).

[Documentação "oficial"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Answer (score 1):

Sim podes, dessa maneira faz o efeito de uma propriedade *read only*.

Ou seja, funciona ter só um getter:

```
var obj = {_valA: 0, _valB:0};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'valA', { // exemplo A
    get: function() {
        return this._valA;
    }
});
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'valB', { // exemplo B
    get: function() {
        return this._valB;
    },
    set: function(value) {
        this._valB = value;
    }
});
console.log(obj.valA); // 0
obj.valA = 10;
console.log(obj.valA); // 0 <- não mudou o valor
console.log('-------')
console.log(obj.valB); // 0
obj.valB = 10;
console.log(obj.valB); // 10 <- mudou o valor com o setter
```

(jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h3ju37ga/)

**mas nesse caso** o mais correto seria ter uma propriedade só de leitura, *read-only* e nesse caso deves fazer assim:

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'val', {
    enumerable: true,
    writable: false,
    value: 5
});

console.log(obj.val); // 5
obj.val = 10;
console.log(obj.val); // 5 <- não muda o valor
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/avgah0ko/